# How can i prove that $A$ is symmetric?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

In given $A,B$ in size of $n\times n$, and, $A=I-AB$.

(I know how to prove that $A$ is invertible and $AB$=$BA$)

If $B$ is symmetric, how can i prove that $A$ is symmetric too?

Comment: $A+AB=I$ implies $A(I+B)=I$. So $A$ is invertible with inverse $I+B$ which then must also be symmetric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is an invertible matrix, then $(M^T)^{-1} = (M^{-1})^T$. Thus if $M$ is symmetric, then $M^{-1}$ is also symmetric. Since $A = I - AB$, we have $A(I+B)=A+AB = I$. $B$ is symmetric, thus $I+B$ is symmetric. $A$ is the inverse of $I+B$, so $A$ is symmetric too.

Comment: very nice proof :)